# Add a Key value to Json String generated from GSON.toJSON

Tags: java, json, gson

```
  String jsonResponse=Utils.getGsonInstance().toJson(Object);
```

jsonResponse returns :

```
[
   {
    "Key":"1",
    "Code": "11",
   },
   {    
    "key":"2",
    "code": "22",
    }
]
```

End result I am looking for is to wrap this JSON-String in another Key E.g.

```
{
 "MainObj": 
  [
   {
    "Key":"1",
    "Code": "11",
   },
   {    
    "key":"2",
    "code": "22",
   }
 ]
}
```

Is there a way I can achieve this using GSON Api ?

I tried ::

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(); 
    jsonObject.put("MainObj",jsonResponse);
```

Output I am getting is :

```
{"MainObj": "[{\"Key\":\"1",\"Code\":\"11\"},   {\"Key\":\"2",\"Code\":\"22\"}]"}
```

Comment: `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("MainObj",jsonResponse.get(i));`

Comment: I don't know if it fulfill  your requirements. But this is how we use to do in android, So that I added this as comment.

Answer (score 1):

Continue with GSON like :

```
public class MainObj {
    @SerializedName("MainObj")
    public List<Key> Main;

    public class Key {
        @SerializedName("Key")
        public String Key;

        @SerializedName("code")
        public String Code;
    }
}
```

And change

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(); 
jsonObject.put("MainObj",jsonResponse);
```

by

```
String tmp = new Gson().toJson(new MainObj());
```